# Set global data like $user

Tags: 7, hooks

On my project, I have a custom table for some custom permissions for users. I want all permissions for a user loaded on each page like `$user`. I created a custom module and set the global variable `$cperms` in `hook_init()` which contains all custom permissions for current logged in user.

These values are available on site pages but I am not sure it is good to use `hook_init()` to set global data. Is there any proper method?

Comment: First, why the custom table? Why not use Drupal permissions and roles? The Drupal user permissions and roles is one of the easiest and most extendable user/permissions scheme that I've seen out there, I highly doubt the need for anything custom vs using the Drupal user/role/permission base. They also integrate with most contrib modules easily. That being said you would want to actually use a custom access function to use in either a preprocessing function or if you are wanting to restrict a view then you would use the access function in a views access plugin. Many ways to use it this way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel here; as @burnsjeremy mentions, there's already an effective system built into Drupal for storing permissions.

[`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) allows any module to define its own custom permissions that can be set per-role. Once implemented, [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access) can be called to check a user for custom permissions.

If you need some data that is more granular (i.e. at the per-user level), the global `$user` object has an array property called `data`. `$user->data` is loaded/saved with the user object and should always be available to you.

Comment: I am trying to maintain user base permissions but not role based that also depends upon current page user is on thats why I had to maintain them in a custom table.

Answer (score 0):

from a custom module you can add global variables by prefixing the variable name with **global** keyword.

```
global $my_global_var;
```

another way to use the variables from anywhere is by using the **variable_get()** and **variable_set()** functions.